# Does TypeORM support fuzzy queries?

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, nest

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository,Like} from 'typeorm'
import { Series } from './series.entity'

@Injectable()
export class SeriesService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Series)
        private seriesRepository: Repository<Series>,
    ) { }

    async findLike(title: string): Promise<Series[]> {
        return this.seriesRepository.findBy({
                title: Like(`%title%`)
        });
    }
}
```

And it reported that "Query Builder is not supported by MongoDB".

So how should I realize the function of fuzzy query?

Answer (score 0):

fine,i read its document again and again.And now i find it that using advanced options in find() can realize fuzzy search.Like this:

```
async findLike(title: string): Promise<Series[]> {
    return this.seriesRepository.manager.getMongoRepository(Series).find({
        where:{
            title: { $regex: title }
        }
    });
}
```

So,if you want to realize fuzzy search or other conditional queries,you can do try it.